# Pivot between two tables with an inner join

Tags: sql-server

I have a query with this result:

[image: Query Result]

And I tried this query to make a pivot

```
with T as (
select  pwv.PayrollMovementHeaderId as HeaderId, 
        CONCAT(w.PaternalSurname, w.PaternalSurname, w.Name) as Worker,
        pv.Code as Code,
        pwv.Value
from PayrollWorkerVariables pwv
join PayrollVariables pv on pv.Id = pwv.PayrollVariableId
join Workers w on w.Id = pwv.WorkerId
) select * from T Pivot ( Value For Code in ([T01],[T02])) as pvt
```

what I need is this result

```
HeaderId - Worker - T01 - T02 ..... - Tn 
-----------------------------------------
aaaaaaaa - bbbbbb  - Val - Val
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` like the following:

```
create table #t (HeaderId varchar(100), Worker varchar(100), Code varchar(10), [Value] varchar(100))

insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T01', '49.7'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T25', '1'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T02', '0'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T13', 'False'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T08', '0.0'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T04', '2'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T06', 'RI'
insert into #t select 'aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'T07', 'True'

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(t.Code) 
            FROM #t t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT HeaderId, Worker, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select HeaderId, Worker, Code, [Value]
                from #t
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max([Value]) for Code in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

print (@query)

execute(@query)
```

Please find the demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9461545581e460734de274428271f19)**.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, now I need to find a way to optimize it, because the way it is now takes a lot of time, like 8 minutes for the almost 44000 rows.